# No web host, only a domain name: Can I use it to send email with Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email, email-forwarding, smtp

I own a domain name, let's say *domain.com*. Is there a way to send and receive email using Gmail's "Send mail as" function? For example, set up an alias *name@domain.com*? Forgive my ignorance, as I'm a total neophyte when it comes to the technical workings of email.

Backstory: I bought a domain name from Google and web hosting through Siteground. I set up gmail to send and receive email for my new email account *name@domain.com* using the "send as" function. The web hosting expired, but I still own the domain, AND for some reason I still receive email that is sent to *name@domain.com*, but I can't send email as this address (I get a "message not delivered" error).

So do I need to get another web host to use an SMTP server? Or can I use Gmail's POP/IMAP and SMTP servers to route mail? And if so, how? It looks like I need an SMTP server address, and a username and password.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that the domain registration is on Google Domains. Right? If so you can use Google Domains' **Email forwarding** feature.

Here is the Google help page how to set it up with detailed instructions https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3251241?hl=en

**Receiving email:**

> Email forwarding allows you to set up alias email addresses. An alias email address is an alternative address that is used as a substitute for an actual email address. All mail sent to the alias email address will be forwarded to the actual email address.

**Sending As:**

> Many email systems will let you send mail using your forwarded email
>   address as the "From" address.
>
> If you are a Gmail User, you can use the Send mail as feature

Comment: I set up the email forwarding as advised, but I don't see an option in Gmail to "send as" that alias. Do you have specific experience with this feature? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Look in the Google Help link the last section of the page, which is *Sending mail from your forwarded email address*

Comment: Ah, thank you. I assumed that the "send as" feature would appear once I set up the forwarding.

Comment: If my answer answered your question please accept as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two options:

1. The way Gmail sends mail from a normal free account using another domain is by logging in to the SMTP server you specify and sending the mail via SMTP. So if you cannot send mail via the SMTP server yourself, Gmail is not going to be able to either.

For this to work, you would need to get someone to host your domain on their SMTP server.

2. The other option is to sign up for Google's "G Suite" or "Google Apps For Work". I've never tried this option.

See the following for more info:

https://gsuite.google.com/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-gmail-with-your-domain-on-digitalocean

https://seasonofcode.com/posts/custom-domain-e-mails-with-postfix-and-gmail-the-missing-tutorial.html